# Confusion on inequality in proof

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

We are tasked to prove the following: $$\forall x \in\mathbb R \forall\epsilon  > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall y \in\mathbb R, |x − y| < \delta : |x^2 − y^2| < \epsilon.$$

In the solution, the lecturer has included some rough work:
"We may express $|x^2-y^2|$ as $|x-y| \cdot |x+y|$. We know that $|x-y| < \delta$.
Now, $|x+y| \le |x|+|y| \le |x| + |x| +\delta=2|x|+\delta$"

Why is it that $|x|+|y| \le |x| + |x| +\delta$? I can't see how he deduced this.

Comment: Show: $|y|<|x|+\delta$ since $|y-x|<\delta.$

Comment: A variant of the triangle inequality is $|y-x|\ge |y|-|x|$ , which gives you $|y|-|x|\le |y-x|=|x-y|<\delta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|x-y|<\delta$.

$$|y|=|y-x+x|\leq |x-y|+|x| <\delta +|x|$$

Comment: Brilliant! This is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the possible value of $y$ will be in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ since $|x-y|<\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|x - y| < \delta$. Then,
$$
x - \delta <y<x + \delta\\
|y| < \max\{| x - \delta|,|x+\delta|\} \le |x| + \delta
$$
Therefore,
$$
|y| - |x| < \delta
$$